# How to handle event in a program running in a cycle (loop)?

Tags: java, event-handling

I´ve been dealing with this for some days now I´ve serach over the internet and tried everything that came up to my mind but nothing works. My problem is that I am making a pexeso game, we have some additionaly library directly from school or something like that which allows us to draw some pictures instead of comad line only... (We didn´t have graphics yet) So my problem is that my game is running in cycle and waiting for my click som I am checking the condition if click was made. And if I want to click I have to have just a method public void `vyberSuradnice(int, int)` declared in my code.

So the problem is that my game is runinng in cycle and checking if click was made. But when the click was made the method `vyberSuradnice` is executed and there I am setting the value off atrrbiute - `cakatNaKlik` on `false`, so click was made and one step of game can be made.. But since the function is running in cycle, then even If I clicked and in  the method `vyberSuradnice` the value of attribute is changed, my function which is running in cycle isn´t respond to that change, so the game isn´t going on. 
this is the method for clicking

```
 public void vyberSuradnice(int paSuradnicaX, int paSuradnicaY) {
        this.riadokOdkry = (paSuradnicaY ) / 25;
        this.stlpecOdkry  = (paSuradnicaX - 10) / 25;
        if (this.riadokOdkry > this.aPocetRiadkov || this.stlpecOdkry > this.aPocetStlpcov) {
            System.out.println("Klikli ste mimo hracieho pola ");
        } else {
            this.cakatNaKlik = false;
        }
    }
```

This the part of code where I am waiting for cakatNaklik - false value

while (uhadol) {

```
 if (!this.cakatNaKlik) {
                if (this.pocetUhadnutych >= (this.aPocetRiadkov * this.aPocetStlpcov) / 2) {
                    uhadol = false;
                }
                this.hraciaPlocha[this.riadokOdkry][this.stlpecOdkry].setUhadnute(true);
```

But even if the value is changed in method vyberSuradnice this condition is not triggered. But when I make something like this :

```
while (uhadol) {
             System.out.print(this.cakatNaKlik);   
                if (!this.cakatNaKlik) {
                    if (this.pocetUhadnutych >= (this.aPocetRiadkov * this.aPocetStlpcov) / 2) {
                        uhadol = false;
                    }
                    this.hraciaPlocha[this.riadokOdkry][this.stlpecOdkry].setUhadnute(true);
```

the game is working like by writing the variable refresh it or something... but I am getting neverending print of true true or false on command line and this is something I can´t afford to have...

I know this may can be dan by threads but it´s something I can´t allowed to make and I am basically trying to do two things at once.

Is there any other to do this that the variable will be refreshed even without that println and the code will work ?

Thanks very much for every help

Comment: you can simply add a `break;` in your if-statement to stop the loop

Comment: I don´t want to break that loop... I want to make that when I click the part of code after the if will be executed then I set the value cakatNaKlik back to true and wait for another click

Comment: beside the if statetment is never reach that´s what my problem i

Comment: so the program prints false but doesn't enter the if?

Comment: No.. when I print the value that if is entered.. but when I removed the print the if isn´t working.. because I only execute the one method where is the while(uhadol) so it´s running in cycle empty and waitng for if... when I click on screen the method vyberSuradnice is executed and there is the value for that if condition changed to false so the if should be entered.. but since I am doing something like one function is running in cycle and the other is executed, then without that print it´s like the function isn´t reacting for that change value

Comment: but the method vyberSuradnice isn´t called directly in java like object.vyberSuradnice()... it´s only called by clicked on screen.. so it change the value of attribute but the other function doesn´t react to it

Comment: and when I print it before the if it acts like with that print the variable is refresh and it reacts.. but without that it isn´t react... and I don´t know with which another way I should do it

Comment: so you simply want to remove the print? if yes just try `this.cakatNaKlik=cakatNaKlik;`

Comment: yes I want to remove the print and make it in different way so the IF would be entered too... Okay I´ve tried this, but isn´t working either.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everybody for help, I finally solved it. I just tried tu put a sleep before the if condition. It only need to sleep for even a one miliseconds and it´s seems that the condition is refreshed so it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Implement an ActionListener interface or extend a class that implements an ActionListener interface. For example:

```
public class MyClass implements ActionListener {

}
```

Register an instance of the event handler class as a listener on one or more components. For example:

```
someComponent.addActionListener(instanceOfMyClass);

instanceOfClass = this; //(if it is handled in the same Class)
```

Include code that implements the methods in listener interface. For example:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
    ...//code that reacts to the action... 
}
```

Reference: 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html

Comment: Thanks, but problem is that I am limited to use only things that we learned in the school by now, So I can´t use button component and action listener right now